# (Android Image View) How to resize the src after remove the background?

Tags: android, android-imageview

How to resize the src after remove the background?

[This is original size of src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd1TC.png)

[After I add the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itc3l.png)

Using code `imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.player_background)`

[After I remove the background in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvmOg.png)

Using code `imageview.setBackground(null) or imageview.setBackgroundResource(0)`

How to solve it?

XML code

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/game_board_x0y4"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/game_icon_text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/game_board"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/game_board"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.015"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/game_board"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/game_board"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.79"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/player" />
```

Comment: I think you need to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set the value of the ImageView values to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Instead, change it to a particular value **slightly smaller** than the original size of the image like so

```
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
scaleType: fitXY //add this line to fit the image uniformly in the given size
```

This will take care of the image resizing.

Edit 1:
use `android:scaleType="center"` or `android:scaleType="matrix"` to disable scaling in your imageview.

Comment: Sorry about that, I already set the "layout_width", "layout_height" and "scaleType" in XML but its not work.

Comment: could you edit your question to include your layout code and your java/kotlin code